# Is it possible to limit the number of autocomplete-box rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you know, `autocomplete` attribute is used for `<input>`s by default. Something like this:

[image]

Ok, I can totally remove that attribute by setting it `off`:

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But I don't want disable it completely. I just want to limit it to *two rows*. Currently it is *six rows*. Anyway, Is there any solution *(even by JS)* to limit the number of that box's rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify array of autocomplete options using jQuery.

```
$("#email").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(yourAutocompleteArray, request.term);
        response(results.slice(0, NUMBER_OF_ROWS_YOU_WANT));
    }
});
```

Comment: Only if using jQuery UI, but he is asking about HTML5's autocomplete property.

Comment: @PaulL. Did you see `jquery` tag in OP's question?

Comment: not saying he can't using jQuery UI as a solution, look as his code provided, he is asking about HTML5 autocomplete.property.

Comment: @PaulL. As far as I know, it is impossible to do it using only HTML5. I've checked [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) article and there is'n anything about number of rows displayed on autocomplete.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171, you are right about no HTML5 option. Just I know from own my experience that it is very easy to miss the whole picture (need jQuery UI in order to achieve what you want, and thinking the solution provided will working. So I just pointed out he need jQuery UI to use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @SoftwareEngineer171 mentioned, you could using jQuery UI as a solution if you need that kind of control which is not available in HTML5 input control.

[Link for example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight)